# Access dialogArguments property (window) in all browsers

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, window

I am trying to access the "dialogArguments" property in a modalWindow. In IE I dont have any trouble if I use window.dialogArguments. But if it try the same code in Chrome or Ff the property is undefined.

In the modal window I have tried to make a function like this:

```
function GetDialogArguments() {
    var arguments;

    if (window.dialogArguments) { // For IE
        arguments = window.dialogArguments;
    }
    else { //For FF and Chrome
        arguments = window.opener;
    }

    return arguments;
}
```

But still I am not getting the arguments that I have passed when I open the modal window (I am getting the DOMWindow object when running the code in Chrome or FF).

Can you help me ?

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Strange, `window.dialogArguments` should work in all modern browsers. Are you perchance calling `window.open()` instead of `window.showModalDialog()` if the current browser is Firefox or Chrome?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The way I was opening the modal window was the problem. 
I have changed now the way that i open the modal windows and it works:   
function OpenPopUpWindow () {
            if (window.showModelessDialog) { // For IE
                showModelessDialog ("mypage.aspx", window);
            } 
            else {
                window.open ("mypage.aspx", "",null);
            }
        }